# How to avoid having a stop loss triggered and simultaneous entry of the counter position on bar completion in a Pine script v4 strategy?

Tags: pine-script

This is in the area of handling stop loss in a strategy. The stop loss code is as below:

**stop_level_long =iff (barcountLongEntry>1,max( strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - sl_long),longStopTrail),0)
take_level_long = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + tp_long)
strategy.exit("Stop/Target Long", "Long", stop=stop_level_long, limit=take_level_long,when=window)//

Sometimes the move for triggering the stop loss  is also triggering the short entry in  the same bar. This results in maximum contracts exceeding 1 even when the pyramiding is set to 1.
Thanking all in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy.exit() does not take inputs as price

for eg, `strategy.exit("Long position", stop = 500) //assume 500 is your stoploss`

is not valid. The inputs have to be in ticks.

A workaround is like this:

```
stopTicks = (long_entry_price - stopLoss)/syminfo.mintick

strategy.exit("Long position",stop = stopTicks)
```

Comment: From reference manual: "Loss (float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (specified in ticks). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position when the specified amount of loss (in ticks) is reached. stop (float) An optional parameter. Stop loss (requires a specific price). If it is specified, a stop order is placed to exit market position at the specified price (or worse)" So loss and stop are two different parameters of the exit. Your comment is true for the "loss" - but not for the "stop" ( price) which work fines in my code. The problem is with simultaneous orders.

Comment: The problem here is that when your stoploss is triggered, the conditions for short position are also being triggered. Do you have calc_on_every_tick = true ?

Comment: Precisely- the issue is simultaneous triggering of both. If i use calc_on_order_fill = true, then back testing results show that this does not happen. But this creates a lookahead bias and back testing results are no longer representative.  So we need to find another  way. Thanks

Comment: Tradingview makes it very clear that even if you have calc_on_every_tick = true, then the strategy you backtest will not be the strategy you implement. The problem is that when your stoploss is hit, the conditions for having a short position are also becoming true, that is why this is happening. I suggest you turn it off, doing so will make your strategy work exactly as it was backtested